# Remote control android device via ip address

Tags: remote-control

Is there a php code to control an android device based on its ip address. Control can be just up to using applications on the android device.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. "PHP code" suggests a development question, which is off-topic here. Asking for "an app for X" is off-topic as well. If you're looking for possibilities to remote-control your Android device from a PC, you might wish to see my list for [Remote Droid 2: Control your Droid from your Computer](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid). Or ask a *specific* question on [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).